# How to search for a changeset by user

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Is there a way to search for or filter changesets by user?

The History view seems very inflexible.

For that matter, is there a way to filter changesets by anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you see a list of your users under Team Members in the Team Explorer tab?  If so then right click on a user and select 'Show Checkin History'.  This will enable you to see a full list of Changesets checked in by the selected user.

There is also a "Find Changesets" toolbar button in the Source Control Explorer tab[image]

Comment: I do have the team members tab, but we have dozens of teams and half of them seem to be configured wrongly (they have a red "x" icon and won't expand), including the one I belong to. The "Find Changesets" button in the Source Control Explorer is exactly what I was looking for, though, thanks! Specifically, I cleared the File field and put in the User ID. That dialog seems like it would correspond to the File.TfsFindChangesets command, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to search by user, but regarding the second part of your question about existing filters : when you're performing a search (right click "Find in Source Control") or a "merge up to a specific version" option, you can select to search by changeset, and then search for a range of changeset or a range of dates.